# How to update the system app by itself with android 9 and above

Tags: android, system, root

I've a device with root access. Here is a system app with a function allow the system app can update by itself. It works on Android 4, but fail on Android 9. The new apk file can be copy to /system/app/ folder correctly, but not update the app after reboot. Here's the code I have:

```
final String libs = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib ";
final String[] commands = new String[]{
    libs + "mount -o rw,remount /",
    libs + "cp -rf " + StorageUtil.getInstance().getRootDir() + "/app.apk /system/app/",
    libs + "chmod 644 /system/app/app.apk",
    libs + "mount -o ro,remount /",
};
RootUtil.executeAsRoot(commands);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured out this issue. First of all, you need to replace the apk file of the app you want to update. So, the path should be /system/app/{AppName}/{AppName}.apk. Then, you need to remove the original apk first. After that you can replace the new apk file. There is a point, you need to keep the /system/app/{AppName} folder and the /system/app/{AppName}/{AppName}.apk file keep the same permission as the others under the /system/app folder. Now, you can reboot your device to use the new version of app. Here's the new version of the code:

```
final String libs = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib ";
final String[] commands = new String[]{
    libs + "mount -o rw,remount /",
    libs + "chmod 666 /system/app/{AppName}/{AppName}.apk",
    libs + "rm /system/app/{AppName}/{AppName}.apk",
    libs + "cp -rf " + "{AppPath}{AppName}.apk" /system/app/{AppName}/",
    libs + "chmod 644 /system/app/{AppName}/{AppName}.apk",
    libs + "chmod 755 /system/app/{AppName}/",
    libs + "mount -o ro,remount /",
};
```